# How should I map numbers to text in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

What is the best practice when it comes to mapping numbers to text in JSON? A [JavaScript map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) would be perfect as I can use numbers for keys, which I can't do with objects:

```
let map = new Map();

map.set(1, 'describe 1');
map.set(2, 'describe 2');
```

... and so on. However you can't use maps in json, as far as I know. Is the best option really just to use an array of arrays?

```
[
  [ 1, 'describe 1' ],
  [ 2, 'describe 2' ]
]
```

Comment: Are you trying to convert an array of strings to a json object that has numeric keys for each string?

Comment: No I'm working on something where certain items are scored and there are descriptions that correspond to those scores. So it would be great if I could use a Map and do something like `descriptions.get(score)` to retrieve the description...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON stands for "JavaScript Object Notation" and is a subset of Javascript--specifically the subset that is used for writing out objects.  The map you're typing creates an object.  That object that the `map.set` function outputs is what you're getting at.  You can see it by doing this.

```
let map = new Map();

map.set(1, 'describe 1');
map.set(2, 'describe 2');
console.log(JSON.stringify(map));
```

I think that you want your numbers to be strings, in which case you can do this:

```
let map = new Map();

map.set('1', 'describe 1');
map.set('2', 'describe 2');
```

However, if your numbers are intended to identify the indexes of items on an array, you might be going for this:

`[null, 'describe 1', 'describe 2']`

Either way, you'll be able to see it with `JSON.stringify`

For more evidence, here's what Chrome outputs with your inputs:

```
> let map = new Map();
undefined
> map.set(1, 'describe 1');
Map {1 => "describe 1"}
> map.set(2, 'describe 1');
Map {1 => "describe 1", 2 => "describe 1"}
```

Which would look like:

`{ 1: 'describe 1', 2: 'describe 2' }`

as a Javascript Object (i.e. JSON)

For more information on JSON, check out http://www.json.org/

Comment: Thank you for the full explanation this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Nitpick: JSON means JavaScript Object Notation.

Comment: @GregBurghardt wierd, they changed it back.  They flipped back and forth on that name for a while now.  I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use the string value "1", "2", and so on as keys in your JSON file, and then call `parseInt` on them if you want to get the number value. You could then write a function that converts your imported JSON file into a Map. Something like

```
function JSONtoMap(src){
  var m = new Map();
  for(var key in src)
    m.set(parseInt(key), src[key])
  return m;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this that will work in JSON.

Use an object with the numbers, converted to strings, as keys (as Weston describes, above): `{'1':'describe 1', '2': 'describe 2'}`

Or an object with the text as keys: `{'describe 1':1, 'describe 2':2}`

Or an array created such that the indexes match the numbers paired with the text at that position in the array: `[,'describe 1', 'describe 2']`